# Prove Verification: show by definition that $\lim_{x \to 9} \sqrt{x-8}=1$

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, continuity

#### Question:

Prove by definition that $\lim_{x \to 9} \sqrt{x-8}=1$

#### Answer:

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta = (1+ \epsilon)^2-1 > 0 \; s.t. \; | \sqrt{x-8} -1 | < \epsilon$ indeed:
1- We can note that $\forall \epsilon>0 , (1+ \epsilon)^2-1>(1- \epsilon)^2-1$ and that $(1- \epsilon)^2-1>-(1+ \epsilon)^2+1$ (trivial to prove).
2- Hence from "1-" we have that if $ |x-9| < (1+\epsilon)^2-1 \Leftrightarrow -(1+\epsilon)^2+1< x-9 < (1+\epsilon)^2-1 $ we can restrict to the case of $x$ verifying $ (1- \epsilon)^2-1 < x-9 < (1+\epsilon)^2-1$
3- So we continue and we get:
$(1- \epsilon)^2 < x-8 < (1+\epsilon)^2 \Leftrightarrow 1-\epsilon < \sqrt{x-8} < 1+\epsilon \Leftrightarrow -\epsilon < \sqrt{x-8} -1 < \epsilon$ and the last expression is equivalent to write $|\sqrt{x-8} -1|<\epsilon$.

Q.E.D.

Is it correct? Thank you.

Comment: Why my question has been down voted? And why should it be closed????

Comment: up anyone can to help me please? (and to explain me why my question has been down voted?)

Comment: Looks fine. I would advise you to write it up better. You don't say $\exists \delta = $ what you are looking for in your proof is just defining a $\delta$ that will force the $\epsilon-\delta$ criteria. This is how you show existence.
You can also use monotonicity and similar things to shorten your arguments at the end. Suppose $x\in ]9-\delta,9+\delta[$, then $\sqrt{1-\delta}<\sqrt{x-8} < \sqrt{1+\delta}$ by strict monotonicity of the square root. The rest follows from your definition of delta.

Comment: Thank for your time and comment. Can you write an answer so I can mark this topic as solved :-) (and re edit the latex because the end of your comment is not readibale enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment of https://math.stackexchange.com/users/632417/snake707 , It seems that my question is correct. I am just writing this answer in order to mark this question as solved.